# Swift Spritekit image resizing itself after presenting a new scene

Tags: xcode, image, swift, sprite-kit

I am adding a sprite to the first screen in the basic SpriteKit template. However whenever I go to the play scene and return to the menu scene the image is enlarged. After checking size and scale mode everything seems to be normal. I am unsure why this is happening.

This is the code for the menu:

```
let playButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "play")


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView)
{
    /* Setup your scene here */

    //Place button in exact middle of the screen
    self.playButton.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

    addChild(self.playButton)

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent)
{
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch: AnyObject in touches
    {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self.playButton
        {
            var scene = PlayJumper()
            let sKView = self.view as SKView!
            sKView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
            scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
            scene.size = sKView.bounds.size

            sKView.presentScene(scene)
        }

    }
}
```

Screenshot of scene before moving to next scene:

[image]

This is the code to return to the menu from the next scene, and the image that is altered after returning to the screen.

```
import SpriteKit

class PlayJumper : SKScene
{


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView){
    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
}

override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent)
{
    for touch: AnyObject in touches
    {
        endGame()
    }
}

func endGame()
{
    if let scene = GameScene.unarchiveFromFile("GameScene") as? GameScene
    {
        let sKView = self.view as SKView!
        sKView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        scene.size = sKView.bounds.size
        scene.scaleMode = .AspectFill
        sKView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}

}
```

Here is the image after moving back to the view, it is slightly larger than the previous image.

[image]

I need the image to stay the same no matter how many times the user goes from the game to the menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only think of two things that can cause this:

1. In your viewController, you may have changed the scene anchorPoint of the menu and when you go back to the menu you do not set it as the same thing its set to in the viewController.
2. You may want to use .ResizeFill instead of .AspectFill

Everytime I experienced this problem, it was because of one of these.